# Functional C++ via template abuse

Tags: c++, templates, collections, functional-programming, template-templates

I decided to try to write a functional map implementation in C++ using templates, and this is what I've come up with:

```
template <
    class U, 
    class V, 
    template <class> class T 
>

class T<V> WugMap(
    class T<U>::const_iterator first, 
    class T<U>::const_iterator second, 
    V (U::*method)() const)

{
    class T<V> collection;
    while (first != second)
    {
        collection.insert(collection.end(), ((*(first++)).*method)());
    }
    return collection;
}
```

Now this is all fine and dandy, and even compiles.  Problem is, I have no idea how to actually call it.

Trying the naive way yields the following error:

```
prog.cpp:42: error: no matching function for call to 
‘WugMap(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Container*, std::vector<Container, 
std::allocator<Container> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Container*, 
std::vector<Container, std::allocator<Container> > >, int (Container::*)()const)’
```

As far as I can tell, all of the arguments are correct.  gcc isn't suggesting any alternatives at all, which leads me to believe that my definition of WugMap is suspect, but it compiles fine, so I'm rather lost. Can anyone guide me through this silliness?

If anyone can suggest a better way to write a function like this that will support consuming any type of collection containing any type of object, I'll look into changing it.

[Here's my ideone so far.](http://ideone.com/EJSYS)

I'm currently using Ideone, which is using C++03, gcc 4.3.4.

## Addendum 1

Is this possible in C++11?  It's been hinted that it is.  I know templates in C++11 support varying numbers of arguments so I'll modify my requirements to suit that as well.  I'll put a bit of effort into writing something up, but in the meantime, here are the requirements that I'm looking for:

- Should have a signature something like the following:

  ```
  C2<V, ...> map(const C1<U, ...>&, V (U::*)(...), ...)
  ```

  That's taking some collection C1, containing elements of type U, constructed with some number of default parameters, by reference, and also taking some member function (returning V and taking some number of arguments of unknown types) of U, and then taking, in order, arguments to be passed to the member function.  The function will finally return a collection of type C2 containing elements of type V and being initialized with an unknown number of default parameters.
- Should be chainable:

  ```
  vector<int> herp = map(
                     map(
                          set<Class1, myComparator>(),
                     &Class1::getClass2, 2, 3),
                     &Class2::getFoo);
  ```
- Bonus points if I don't have to have template arguments or any other extra verbosity when using it.

`std::transform` is great, but not chainable.

Comment: Does it need to be a container? [`std::transform`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/transform/) in `<algorithm>` already does this with iterators.

Comment: @JonPurdy: Let's pretend that std::transform doesn't exist.  Also, one feature that this implementation aims to provide that std::transform doesn't is it takes a pointer-to-member-function (I don't think std::transform can behave this way without a wrapper object).  Also, std::transform mutates a collection, this is designed to produce a new collection of a possibly different type.

Comment: @DyP: you know, that might have something to do with it, though exactly what, I can't fathom.  There is some sort of subtle rules about whether to use `class` or `typename` that don't come into play unless template-templates are involved.  That might explain why its compiling but not being seen as a function though.

Comment: @Wug: Who says `std::transform` cannot apply pointer to members? In C++11 you can use generalized binders or lambda expressions. In C++03 IIRC you can also bind a pointer to member and alternatively you can use generalized binders from boost.bind. I mean, I understand trying to do this for the sake of it, for fun or to learn, but I would not do that in production.

Comment: Now related to the question, how are you trying to call it in the *naïve* way? Can you post the code?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: it *was* in the linked ideone but I have been screwing with it and it doesn't look quite the same.  I'm about to edit the question so hold

Comment: Well.... I somehow got my g++ to compile a version which deduces _all_ necessary template arguments. BUT it's even my first time to work with variadic templates, so please review, I guess it contains errors: http://ideone.com/ZGXHI

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Template arguments can never be deduced from nested types. Even if `U` and `V` can be deduced from the member function pointer, you won't be able to deduce the template type `T`.

Explicitly specifying the template arguments as in the link to [ideone](http://ideone.com/EJSYS) (I didn't the the link before writing the statement above) doesn't work either, mainly because the template arguments for `std::vector` are not just a single type `T`! `std::vector` takes a value type and an allocator type. Fixing things up is getting fairly ugly:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Container
{
public:
    Container() {}
    Container(int _i) : i(_i) {}

    int get_i() const {return i;}

    int i;
};

    template <
        class U, 
        class V, 
        template <typename...> class T 
    >

    T<V> WugMap(
        typename T<U>::const_iterator first, 
        typename T<U>::const_iterator second, 
        V (U::*method)() const)
    {
        T<V> collection;
        while (first != second)
        {
            collection.insert(collection.end(), ((*(first++)).*method)());
        }
        return collection;
    }

int main()
{
    vector<Container> containers;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) containers.push_back((Container(i)));

    WugMap<Container, int, std::vector>(
        containers.begin(), containers.end(), &Container::get_i);
}
```

Comment: He's not deducing it, he's explicitly specifying it: `WugMap<Container, int, vector>(...);`

Comment: This would imply that I'd be able to explicitly specify the template arguments with `WugMap<Container, int, vector>(...)`, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: I changed to code to remove the parameter and used variadics instead.

Comment: This is more along the lines of what I was hoping to eventually achieve.  I've muddled with it a bit more, you can look at it here: http://ideone.com/S0JmR

Answer (score 2):

Not really sure whether this should be an answer, but heck:

```
std::vector<std::string> src = f();
std::vector<std::string::size_type> sizes; 
sizes.reserve(src.size());
// Actual transformation:
std::transform( src.begin(), src.end(), std::back_inserter(sizes), 
                [](std::string const& s) { return s.size(); } );
```

Similar things can be done manually, but there is really no point in reinventing the reinvented wheel.

As to what is different in the `std::transform` case, it does not try to bind types so tightly, it takes `Iter1` for the first two arguments, `Iter2` for the third argument and `Functor` for the third. There are no checks on the interface to guarantee that `Iter1` and `Iter2` are iterators into the same type of container, or that `Functor` will transform from the value type in the first container to the value type in the second.

Comment: The whole point was not to use std::transform because it doesnt behave quite the way I wanted it to, and since it was an exercise reinventing the wheel is ok.

Comment: What part of `std::transform` does not work as you want it? It might be simpler to start from `transform` and improve it to support your needs than starting from scratch (in particular the lesser strict requirements on the arguments of `transform` are a good advantage that is not present in your approach --> for example mixing containers for the input and output: generating a `set` from a `vector`